# JSON deserialisation with a CustomCreationConverter to create the type and inject data

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization, constructor-injection

I have an task based application that needs to inject information into some tasks. The tasks can be cloned or stored in a save file, in each case the class is serialised as JSON. The application information passed to the tasks is not stored as it only persists the application session.

```
public interface IApplicationData { }
public class ApplicationData : IApplicationData { }

public interface ITask {
   IApplicationData Data { get; }
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class Task : ITask, ICloneable {
   protected Task(IApplicationData data = null) {
      Data = data;
   }

   public IApplicationData Data { get; }

   public object Clone() {
      var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
         TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
      };
      settings.Converters.Add(new TaskCreator(Data));

      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, settings);

      // Reflection equivalent of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);
      var expectedParameters = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(JsonSerializerSettings) };
      var method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.IsGenericMethod && mi.IsStatic && mi.IsPublic && mi.GetParameters().Select(pi => pi.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(expectedParameters)).Single();
      return method.MakeGenericMethod(this.GetType()).Invoke(null, new object[] { json, settings });
   }
}
```

Tasks can 'opt-in' to holding the application data or not so might look something like the below:

```
public class NoDataTask : Task {
   public NoDataTask() { }
}

public class DataTask : Task {
   public DataTask(IApplicationData data) : base(data) { }
}
```

I implemented a `CustomCreationConverter` to create a new instance of the relevant class when deserialising from JSON (you may have noticed this is being utilised in the `Clone()` implementation in the `Task` base class shown above.

```
public class TaskCreator : CustomCreationConverter<Task> {
   //public TaskCreator() { } // uncomment to try using converter with JsonProperty attribute in Project

   private readonly IApplicationData _data;
   public TaskCreator(IApplicationData data) {
      _data = data;
   }

   public override Task Create(Type objectType) {
      var hasDataConstructor = objectType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IApplicationData) }) != null;
      return hasDataConstructor ? (Task)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, _data) : (Task)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
   }
}
```

This works exactly as required on the `Clone()` method, the `objectType` received is of the DerivedClass (`DataTask` in the below example)

```
var data = new ApplicationData();
var dataTask = new DataTask(data);
var dataTaskCloneData = ((DataTask)dataTask.Clone()).Data; // still has data intact - excellent
```

However I am unsure as to how to make this work for the case of storing the tasks. I currently have a `Project` class that contains a `List<ITask>` that I serialise / de-serialise. That works perfectly with respect to the data in each task, however I have been unable to inject the `ApplicationData` into the deserialised task instances.

```
[DataContract]
public class Project {
   [DataMember]
   //[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(TaskCreator))] // uncomment to force use of converter
   public List<ITask> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

```
var project = new Project {
   Tasks = new List<ITask> {
      new NoDataTask(),
      new DataTask(data)
   }
};

var serialiserSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
   TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
serialiserSettings.Converters.Add(new TaskCreator(data));

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(project, serialiserSettings);
var projectCopy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(json, serialiserSettings);

var projectCopyTask2Data = projectCopy.Tasks[1].Data; // data is null - bad
```

I have found that due to the project containing a `List<ITask>` the converter isn't utilised. I could add a converter of `CustomCreationConverter<ITask>` but either way the `objectType` passed to the converter is always of type `ITask` whereas I need to derived class to be able to create an appropriate new instance.

Adding the `[JsonProperty]` attribute provides the ability for the converter to be used as-is, but I'm unaware of a method that I can apply this without it using the parameterless constructor which is useless given my implementation as the `IApplicationData` would always be null.

.NET Fiddle example here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdyfDv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to solve my issue by writing my own JsonConverter (based heavily on `CustomCreationConverter` in `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters` - [GitHub link](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/CustomCreationConverter.cs)) as follows:

```
public class TaskCreator : JsonConverter<ITask> {
    private readonly IApplicationData _data;
    public TaskCreator(IApplicationData data) {
        _data = data;
    }

    public override ITask ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, [AllowNull] ITask existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Determine and create the task by reading the type in the JSON
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var jsonType = jObj["$type"]?.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonType)) throw new JsonSerializationException("Cannot determine type of task to create.");
        var type = Type.GetType(jsonType);
        if (type == null) throw new JsonSerializationException($"Could not find the task type {jsonType}");
        var value = Create(type);
        if (value == null) throw new JsonSerializationException("No object created.");

        reader = jObj.CreateReader();
        serializer.Populate(reader, value);
        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an object which will then be populated by the serializer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <returns>The created object.</returns>
    public ITask Create(Type objectType) {
        var hasDataConstructor = objectType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IApplicationData) }) != null;
        return hasDataConstructor ? (ITask)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, _data) : (ITask)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, [AllowNull] ITask value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotSupportedException($"{ nameof(TaskCreator) } should only be used while deserializing.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

The 'magic' happens in `ReadJson()` where the derived class of `ITask` is pulled out from the json '$type' and created using reflection. This does require that TypeNameHandling is set to `TypeNameHandling.Objects`, which is it in my serialiser settings.

To use this I can remove the `JsonProperty` attribute from the `Project` class and ensure that the `JsonSerializerSettings` includes the converter as so:

```
var data = new ApplicationData("Hello World");
var project = new Project {
    Tasks = new List<ITask> {
        new NoDataTask(),
        new DataTask(data)
    }
};
var serialiserSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
serialiserSettings.Converters.Add(new TaskCreator(data));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(project, serialiserSettings);
var projectCopy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(json, serialiserSettings);
```

A fully working example (.NET fiddle ) here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ecrz2S

I'm still very much open to alternative approaches if anyone has one to suggest, as this solution does still feel a little 'hacky' to me.